# Cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'System.Data.Linq.Binary' error

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-2

In the program I'm currently working on, my table has a `Create_Timestamp` column, which I defined as `timestamp`.

When I'm working with my data context and my form values in my controller on the `HttpPost`, I'm trying the following:

```
NewsArticle article = new NewsArticle();
article.Create_Timestamp = System.DateTime.Now;
```

The error I get is `Cannot implicitly convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'System.Data.Linq.Binary'`

I've tried to force the conversion, but I'm unsure exactly what I'm doing at this point.

Is it possible in C# to do this conversion and still have Linq be happy with me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you are using the SQL timestamp type in your table and you are expecting it to be a DateTime.  Timestamp isn't really meant for holding Date/Time information.  From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(SQL.80).aspx):

> timestamp is a  data type that exposes
>   automatically generated binary
>   numbers, which are guaranteed to be
>   unique within a database. timestamp is
>   used typically as a mechanism for
>   version-stamping table rows. The
>   storage size is 8 bytes.storage size is 8 bytes.

Change your column "Create_Timestamp" to DateTime and you should be fine.